# Exportar resultado addEVentLIstener de un .js a otro .js

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un resultado de una URL concatenada que realicé en `index.js` y ese resultado lo necesito exportar o compartir en `game.js` para que cargue una nueva página **html** (`game.html`) con los valores seleccionados en la **URL**(`API`).

El valor obtenido en `index.js` tiene el nombre de `newUrl`, la cual debe ir en `game.js` en el comentario que especifiqué.

*index.js*

```
//SELECT CATEGORY
//CATEGORY => 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 32

const obj = {
    url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20',
    category: '',
    difficulty: ''
}

let newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('');

function selectCat() {
    var c = document.getElementById('cat').value;
    console.log(c);
    obj.category = c;
    newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('');
}

//SELECT DIFFICULTY
//DIFFICULTY => any, easy, medium, hard
function selectDiff() {
    var d = document.getElementById('diff').value;
    console.log(d);
    obj.difficulty = d;
    newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('');
}

/*NEST VALUE TO CATEGORY AND DIFFICULTY
    NEXT TO THE URL TO GET THE NEWURL*/

//CLICK EVENT BUTTON

document.getElementById('fetch')
 .addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    console.log(newUrl);

});
```

*game.js*

```
fetch(
    // Acá va el resultado que se obtuvo en index.js
    )
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(loadedQuestions => {
      console.log(loadedQuestions.results);
      questions = loadedQuestions.results.map(loadedQuestion => {
        const formattedQuestion = {
          question: loadedQuestion.question
        };

        const answerChoices = [...loadedQuestion.incorrect_answers];
        formattedQuestion.answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        answerChoices.splice(
        formattedQuestion.answer - 1,
        0,
        loadedQuestion.correct_answer
        );
        answerChoices.forEach((choice, index) => {
          formattedQuestion["choice" + (index + 1)] = choice;
        });

        return formattedQuestion;
      });

      startGame();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justo ahora necesitaba lo mismo y encontré una forma espero te sirva, en resumidas cuentas es algo así.

En mi página tengo un textbox y un botón, al dar clic el botón toma el valor de ese cuadro de texto y va a otra página sin perder ese valor.

En mi primer página tengo una función que toma el valor de ese cuadro de texto que el usuario puede llenar, en su respectivo archivo.js, usando las llamadas localStorage que se guardan como si fueran variables de sesión, donde lo que va entre comillas es el nombre de tu variable localStorage y seguido del valor que quieras enviar.

```
function busquedaClick() {
    var entrada = $("#txtBusqueda").val();
    if(entrada != ""){
        localStorage.setItem("busquedaUsuario", entrada); //donde "busquedaUsuario" es el nombre que le das a ese localStorage y entrada es la variable que yo deseo enviar, y al asignar se utiliza setItem
        window.location.href = "MiOtraPagina.aspx"; //como valide que el valor del usuario no es nulo esta línea me envía a otra página.
    }
```

Y en mi segunda página tiene OtroArchivo.js que al entrar toma el valor de esa variable localStorage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    busquedaUsuario();
});

function busquedaUsuario() {
    var entrada = localStorage.getItem("busquedaUsuario"); //y para obtener el valor del anterior archivo.js se lo puedes asignar a otra variable y solo colocas el nombre de ese localStorage y utilizando la palabra getItem
    alert(entrada);
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Lo intentare

Comment: Me sirvió de maravilla! Muchas gracias!